# To prove that $f(A)$ is compact in $(Y,e)$.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ and $(Y,e)$ be metric spaces, $A \subset X$ is compact and $\eta$ a fixed number and $f : A \to Y$ a function such that $$e(f(x),f(y)) \leq \eta d(x,y) \ , \ \forall x,y \in A$$ To prove that $f(A)$ is compact in $(Y,e)$.

Since the function $f$ satisfies the property $e(f(x),f(y)) \leq \eta d(x,y) \ , \ \forall x,y \in A$ we can conclude that $f$ is continuous and we know that continuous image of a compact set is compact. Hence $f(A)$ is compact in $(Y,e)$.

Is the working of the proof correct?

Comment: Yes, absolutely!